# Replacing <br> tag in asp multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with textbox in a datagrid. Before saving the data into the database, I replace the newline with `<br>` by using following script :

```
description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>")
```

Working fine, it's replacing the newline with `<br>`. Then I need to fetch the data into the textbox again for editing. I've tried to replace the `<br>` with newline by using following script :

```
data.description = ((TextBox)dgrid.Items[i].FindControl("description")).Text;
data.description = data.description.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");
```

But it's not working, do you guys have any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the Text value back, you're changing data.description. Try changing it to something like

```
Textbox txt = ((TextBox)dgrid.Items[i].FindControl("description"));
txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);
```

There's likely a better place to do this, but without seeing everything, it's hard to say.

Comment: yes. i know it's hard without seeing the complete script, but it'll be too overwhelmed. question : i try the `((TextBox)dgrid.Items[i].FindControl("description"));` but it returned an error. is it okay to leave it without `.Text` ?

Comment: ((TextBox)dgrid.Items[i].FindControl("description")) should be returning to you the Textbox control itself. If it's not, then the Grid isn't finding that control. I tried to shorten it up, but you could try string s = ((TextBox)dgrid.Items[i].FindControl("description")).Text;
((TextBox)dgrid.Items[i].FindControl("description")).Text = s.Replace("<br>", "\r\n");

Comment: Recommend you use Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n".

Comment: i finally solved it. thx Doozer Blake for the point. also for @rickschott !